# add alert for mount point in netdata monitoring

Tags: monitoring, netdata

I have some shares from 4 remote servers that I've mounted to my netdata server. Due to power outages and other issues, the remote servers are not always online and would be a very valuable addition to my netdata monitoring if any of the mount points is available or not and send alerts accordingly

read documents and health monitoring section on netdata site but to no avail. Disk monitoring is not what I need, but mount point absence/presence

is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netdata monitors mount points but it automatically removes the charts and their alarms when they are unmounted. Now that I think of it, it would be nice to add an option in netdata.conf to disable that functionality for cases like yours. Please request it at github.

What you can do today, is to create a simple bash plugin for netdata that will monitor anything you like and send metrics to netdata. Then based on the values you send, you can create an alarm. So, for example you could monitor the number of mount points and report their number to netdata (i.e. mounts = 10), or you could create a chart for each mount point and attach an alarm template to each of them.

However, I think you should probably use `fping` plugin to monitor the availability and the quality of the link between your servers. `fping` charts at netdata already have plenty of alarms attached, so you will be notified immediately if the remote server is not reachable or the connection is slow. Check this: https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki/fping-Plugin